# PHP: preg_split caret and hash tag string

Tags: php

How to split filename where is caret?
Like:

> 6543534-001#2016-06-13^16.00.54.JPG

And I want split out # and ^. Like 2016-06-13 16.00.54

I've tryed this one:

```
<?php $str = $file['name']; $chars = preg_split('/^#/', $str); print_r($chars); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The caret `^` matches the beginning of a line, so you need to escape it to use it as a normal character
2. Use the pipe `|` for alternation, to match either of the characters

So you want this:

```
$chars = preg_split('/\^|#/', $str);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/PrTEJ

---

Alternatively you could use the character class `[#^]` like this (HT @chris85):

```
$chars = preg_split('/[#^]/', $str);
```

Either way you'll get an array with three elements.

---

**Pro tip:** Combine this with the `list()` method and pull your string apart into separate variables in one step!

```
list($number, $date, $filename) = preg_split('/[#^]/', $str);

echo $date . " " . $filename; // 2016-06-13 16.00.54.JPG
```

Comment: Yup that would only match `^#` together. You need the pipe to match either one.